# Removing Activity from BackStack (Flag_Activity_no_history) does not work

Tags: java, android, android-activity, back-stack

I've a Start button in my MainActivity. If I click on this button I go to the next Activity (InfoActivity). Now, I want to remove the MainActivity from the BackStack, if I click on the button. I've tried this:

```
View.OnClickListener startButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

But that removes not the MainActivity from the BackStack, it removes the InfoActivity from the BackStack.

I know that I could insert the flag into the AndroidManifest. But that is not possible for me, because if I go to the PreferencesActivity from the MainActivity and I using the flag in the AndroidManifest, the MainActivity is removed if I return from the PreferencesActivity back to the MainActivity.

So I want to remove the MainActivity from the BackStack, if I click on the button Start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add finish(); 
Like this :

```
View.OnClickListener startButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish(); 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As said you should use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` on the activity you dont want to track in your case on MainActivity.
Other way to do it is `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` on your Info activity this will clear whole history (even things before MainActivity)